# Could not get XmlDocument.Save to save into a specific file located in a specific location

Tags: c#, asp.net

Strange, I can't get ASP.Net project (using C# mode) to log result into my `D:\Web.log` file and also no exception was thrown.

Is there something wrong with my simple code?

```
    private static XmlDocument _doc = new XmlDocument();
    private static string LogFileName = "D:\\Web.log";

    static void LogToFile(string WebAddress, string IPAddress, string Title)
    {
        if (File.Exists(@"" + LogFileName + ""))
            _doc.Load(@"" + LogFileName + "");
        else
        {
            var root = _doc.CreateElement("Web");
            _doc.AppendChild(root);
        }

        try
        {
            var el = (XmlElement)_doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(_doc.CreateElement("Web"));
            el.SetAttribute("Title", Title);
            el.AppendChild(_doc.CreateElement("WebAddress")).InnerText = WebAddress;
            el.AppendChild(_doc.CreateElement("IPAddress")).InnerText = IPAddress;
            _doc.Save(@"" + LogFileName + "");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried to debug the code?

Comment: @VictorMukherjee Yes, I debug the code but at the worst, I only see this message `A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@""` and leading `""` from all instances of `@"" + LogFileName + ""`.

They are not needed as you have already escaped the variable `LogFileName`.

Comment: Nothing happen after doing what you mention

Answer (score 0):

By removing the file `D:\Web.log` that I created, it is now able to append the file.